# Loop through fields in jQuery to look for required fields

Tags: jquery, forms

I'm used to working with jQuery and check every field individually.

But now I've many different forms on a website and I'd like to write one function that would loop through all fields who have a class name "required".  If one of the field has the class required and is empty, append a class "error" to that field.

How would I go about doing that ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your submit handler:

```
$('.required').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    if(!$this.val()) $this.addClass('error');
});
```

Comment: Won't that loop through the required fields of every form, not just the one that was submitted?

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
function markEmptyRequiredFields (form) {
    $('.required', form).val(function(index, value) {
      if (value == "") {
        $(this).addClass("error");
      }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
markEmptyRequiredFields($("#myformId"));
```